# c++ namespace / identifier issues

Tags: c++, namespaces, identifier

I am a novice in C++ and I am encountering difficulties understanding how to handle more than 1 namespace at the same time. In my MVC application, the view needs a reference to the controller to forward the actions, while the controller needs a reference to the view to display somethings.

I have stripped out almost all from my application, and I still have a lot of compilation errors about nomespace and undeclared identifiers. This is the stripped code:

```
 #ifndef _geometria
#define _geometria

namespace core_stuff {

/*this namespace contains Model and Controller */

class Model {

public:
    Model();
    //void doSomething();

};

class Controller {

public:
    Controller();
    void setView(ui_stuff::View v);

};

}

namespace ui_stuff {

/*this namespace contains View and other UI classes libraries, not included here because I am semplifying the whole stuff */

class View {

public:
    View();
    void setController(core::Controller c);

};

}


#endif
```

and this is the implementation:

```
#include "geometria.h"
#include <iostream>


//implementation of core_stuff namespace  

core_stuff::Model::Model() { }

core_stuff::Controller::Controller() { }

void core_stuff::Controller::setView(ui_stuff::View v) {
//do some kind of operation in my view
}


//implementation of ui_stuff namespace*/

ui_stuff::View::View() { /* */ }

void ui_stuff::View::setController(core_stuff::Controller c) {
//do some kind of operation on the controller
}



/* main */
int main (int nArgs, char* args[]) {
core_stuff::Model m;
core_stuff::Controller c;
ui_stuff::View v;
v.setController(c);
c.setView(v);
}
```

The first of a very long list of compile errors involves the

```
void setView(ui_stuff::View v);
```

line in the header file, unable to access to ui_stuff namespace:

line(20): error C2653: 'ui_stuff' is not the name of a class or a namespace

How am i supposed to fix this?

Comment: Move the namespace `ui_stuff` before namespace `core_stuff`.

Comment: To elaborate on Aloks comment, c++ is parsed in order. It doesn't read the whole file and then try to figure out the types, they need to be in order.

Comment: can you define and then declare namespaces like you can functions so that you don't have to worry about order?

Comment: I would also recommend using of "using namespace .." in your implementation file

Comment: @AlokSave I can't or I will have the inverse issue with setController method.

Comment: @TopGunCoder you can declare classes and functions and later define them (see my answer). Whether they are a part of a namespace is irrelevant - you just put them inside `namespace Something { ... }`. You can open the scope of a namespace any number of times.

Comment: Oops I kind of got declare and define backwards. Thanks for helping me understand that a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a forward declaration for `ui_stuff::View` before using it

```
namespace ui_stuff
{
    class View; // a forward declaration of ui_stuff::View
}

namespace core_stuff
{
   class Controller {
       void setView(ui_stuff::View& v);
   };
}

namespace ui_stuff
{
   class View
   {
   public:
        void setController(core_stuff::Controller& c);
   };
}
```

I've also passed it in as a reference. That's probably what you want (not a copy of the view).

A short explanation why I changed your declaration: you can't pass a `View` by value to a method of the `Controller` **and** pass a `Controller` by value to the `View`. This is because, when you pass by value, the whole object you pass has to be defined. You can't fully define the controller before the view because the controller depends on the complete definition of the view. But you can't define the view before the controller for the same reason, hence the "pass by reference" bit.

Once both classes are declared, you can define the way they interact with each other.

Answer (score 1):

As dutt saide, C++ is parsed in order. It means at each line of C++ code, the compiler knows only what was defined so far.

To solve your problem you should just move the ui_stuff before the core stuff, but you should also take a look at class stub. Example:

```
namespace ui_stuff {
class View; //This class exists but I will not define it yet.
}
```

The problem is that you can **not** pass a View as copy, because you do not know exactly what is View. But, you can pass as a *pointer* or *reference* (because neither pointer neither reference needs to know the size of the data).

So, in your code, instead of doing this:

```
class Controller {

public:
    Controller();
    void setView(ui_stuff::View v);

};
```

You would do this:

```
class Controller {

public:
    Controller();
    void setView(ui_stuff::View& v);

};
```

The `&` indicates that you are expecting a reference of the an already existing View, instead of a new copy.

Comment: As I said in another comment, I cant invert the order, or i will have the opposed issue: the setController method of View will not find the Controller class and ui_core namespace.

Comment: That's why you should use class stub. Did you get the point of the reference (aka &)? I can elaborate a little more if you need.